# HTML Sortby using select option

Tags: html, sql

i have been trying to make a if statement where it get the value of the selected option and run search sql to get the needed data but i won't work.. i would rather not create IF statement for each option as there are many of them which will make IF statement hard to track.

things i did: i know it can work with Weapons.php?sortby=Axe but this will require long IF statement for each option so i wanted to break it down into 1 single IF statement for the entire Select option.

below code works by generating a new page and linked as http://localhost:8082/GameDataBase/Axe 
which is i am trying to make it appear as  http://localhost:8082/GameDataBase/Weapons.php?sortby=Axe

my current code so far

```html
<td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">
<select name="weapontypeselect" style="background-color:#555; color: white;" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"><option value="">-</option>
<option value="Axe">Axes</option>
<option value="Sword">Swords</option>
<option value="Hammer">Hammers</option>
<option value="Gauntlet">Gauntlets</option>
<option value="Longbow">Longbows</option>
<option value="Shortbow">Shortbows</option>
<option value="Quiver">Quivers</option>
<option value="Flail">Flails</option>
<option value="Mace">Maces</option>
<option value="Wand">Wands</option>
<option value="Shield">Shields</option>
<option value="Chakram">Chakrams</option>
<option value="Fan">Fans</option>
<option value="Focuse">Focuses</option>
<option value="Stave">Staves</option>
<option value="Grimoire">Grimoires</option>
<option value="Orb">Orbs</option>
<option value="Puppet">Puppets</option>
<option value="Bubble Blaster">Bubble Blasters</option>
<option value="Cannon">Cannons</option>
<option value="Powerglove">Powergloves</option>
</select></td>
```

below is the IF statement i am trying to use for all the above options

```html
if ($_GET['weapontypeselect'])
 {
   $sql="SELECT * FROM `weapons` WHERE `weapon_type` = ".$_GET['weapontypeselect']."   ";
 }
```

Comment: Use a prepared PHP statement with a placeholder, and then bind the selected option.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please give an example on how to do that!? i googled and found https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp